# Oracle - Index on large table not used

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing

I have two tables MP_LM and MP_BS, these two are joined as below to a view and used in the select statement.

```
CREATE VIEW MV_MP_LM_V (MP_ID,ID,PID,NAME,IS_D) AS
SELECT C.mp_ID,C.BS_ID ID,NULL      PID,C.BS_NM NAME,'Y'       IS_D FROM MP_BS C UNION
SELECT CM.mp_ID,CM.LM_ID ID,CM.IT_ID PID,CM.LM_NM NAME,CM.IS_D FROM MP_LC_REF_ORIG CM WHERE FLG = 'Y' ;
```

The table MP_BS has PK as below.

```
ALTER TABLE MP_BS ADD CONSTRAINT MP_BS_PK PRIMARY KEY (MP_ID, BS_ID, BS_NM);
```

Below is the Select that I am running.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ID,
              PID,
              NAME,
              DECODE (pid,
                      NULL, DECODE (id, -1, NULL, id || '$'),
                      pid || '$' || id)
                 tree_id,
              DECODE (ID, -1, 0, 1) s1
         FROM  MV_MP_LM_V, TABLE (MV_SPLITARR5 (336700164 , ',', '$')) c
        WHERE     mp_ID = c.id1
              AND IS_D= 'Y'
              AND ID <> -1
              AND (   0 = 0
                   OR (    0 > 0

                            ))
     ORDER BY s1, DECODE (pid, NULL, 0, 1), name;
```

For the above select, without the index MP_BS_PK , the select is taking 35 secs, below is the plan..

```
Plan hash value: 2313865915

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name               | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                    |   206M|   123G|       |    56M  (1)|188:17:27 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                       |                    |   206M|   123G|   131G|    56M  (1)|188:17:27 |
|   2 |   HASH UNIQUE                        |                    |   206M|   123G|   131G|    28M  (1)| 94:49:48 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN                         |                    |   206M|   123G|       |   410K  (1)| 01:22:09 |
|   4 |     COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| MV_SPLITARR5       |  8168 | 16336 |       |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     VIEW                             | MV_MP_LM_V         |  2529K|  1546M|       |   409K  (1)| 01:21:56 |
|   6 |      SORT UNIQUE                     |                    |  2529K|  1489M|  1572M|   409K  (1)| 01:21:56 |
|   7 |       UNION-ALL                      |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  8 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL             | MP_BS              |   121K|  2964K|       |   377   (1)| 00:00:05 |
|*  9 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL             | MP_LM_REF_ORIG     |  2408K|  1486M|       | 79820   (1)| 00:15:58 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("MP_ID"=TO_NUMBER(SYS_OP_ATG(VALUE(KOKBF$),1,2,2)))
   8 - filter("C"."BS_ID"<>(-1))
   9 - filter("CM"."LM_ID"<>(-1) AND "FLG"='Y' AND "CM"."IS_D"='Y')

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

And with the pk, the select is taking 10 secs , and below is the plan for this.

```
Plan hash value: 2486203413

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name               | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                    |       |  1929 | 26028   (1)| 00:05:13 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                       |                    |       |  1929 | 26028   (1)| 00:05:13 |
|   2 |   HASH UNIQUE                        |                    |       |  1929 | 26027   (1)| 00:05:13 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN                         |                    |     3 |  1929 | 26026   (1)| 00:05:13 |
|   4 |     VIEW                             | MV_MP_LM_V         |    10 |  6410 | 25997   (1)| 00:05:12 |
|   5 |      SORT UNIQUE                     |                    |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |       UNION-ALL                      |                    |       |       |            |          |
|*  7 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN          | MP_BS_PK           |   121K|  2964K|   192   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|*  8 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL             | MP_LM_REF_ORIG     |  2408K|  1486M| 79820   (1)| 00:15:58 |
|   9 |     COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| MV_SPLITARR5       |  8168 | 16336 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("MP_ID"=TO_NUMBER(SYS_OP_ATG(VALUE(KOKBF$),1,2,2)))
   7 - filter("C"."BS_ID"<>(-1))
   8 - filter("CM"."LM_ID"<>(-1) AND "FLG"='Y' AND "CM"."IS_D"='Y')

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

I researched lots of things, but couldn't find out why the pk/index on the smaller table gives faster performance.

No. of rows in each table are:

```
MP_LM_REF_ORIG :- 10241670
MP_BS :- 147575
```

I tried creating index on table MP_LM_REF_ORIG on the id MP_ID, but that index is not used.

Can someone please explain how does this index on MP_BS help in better performance.

Comment: What is the purpose of this:    AND (   0 = 0    OR (    0 > 0 ) ) ??  Try adding a hint to use the index?

Comment: The index fast full scan is clearly faster than table full scan, but seems that does'nt explain the speed of second query. How many record yields this query: `SELECT CM.mp_ID,CM.LM_ID ID,CM.IT_ID PID,CM.LM_NM NAME,CM.IS_D FROM MP_LC_REF_ORIG CM WHERE FLG = 'Y'  and IS_D='Y';` ?

Comment: @OldProgrammer -  AND ( 0 = 0 OR ( 0 > 0 ) )  is query framed with variable substituted. I have index on MP_LC_REF_ORIG(MP_ID), but even if I give the index hint, its not working..
    SELECT  /*+ INDEX(MP_LM_REF_ORIG   IDX_MP_LM_REF  ) */     ID,  PID, .........

Comment: @FlorinGhita - the table MP_LC_REF_ORIG with the two filters has 2653814 records.

Answer (score 0):

There are, at least, 2 causes:

1. `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` instead of `TABLE ACCESS FULL` i.e. instead of a full scan on a table it is used a full scan on the index, which can be sensible smaller then corresponding table
2. `UNION` requires duplicate rows to be removed and this, in plan, is represented by an `union all` followed by `sort unique`. When the index is used, data returned by using the index is already sorted so here can be an another gain in performance.